# Pandas DataFrame bar plot with sort_values by other column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a Pandas DataFrame. I want to plot two columns' values with bar plot, and the bar plot sorts values by the other column.

For example, I want to sort values in descending order by column `a_b`(sum of column `a` and `b`).
In addition, the xlabel is rotated, I want to fix it.

Your help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
a = pd.Series([4,8,6,7,8,3,9,7])
b = pd.Series([3,6,8,3,4,6,10,4])
a_b = a+b
df = pd.concat([a,b,a_b],axis=1,join='inner')
df.columns = ['a','b','c']

df[['a','b']].sort_values(by='a',ascending=False).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sort dataframe first by `c` then plot with.

```
df.sort_values('c', ascending=False)[['a','b']].plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Fix the rotation problem using `rot=0` in @piRSquared answer.

```
df.sort_values('c', ascending=False)[['a','b']].plot.bar(stacked=True, rot=0)
```

[image]