# Sort stacked column chart by total value - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort the following table based on the total units sold (y-axis)
[image]

This is the dataframe I plotted:

```
              JP_Sales  NA_Sales  EU_Sales
Genre                                     
Action          158.66    861.80    516.48
Adventure        52.01    102.06     63.79
Fighting         87.15    220.74    100.00
Misc            106.67    402.48    213.82
Platform        130.65    445.99    200.67
Puzzle           56.68    122.01     50.53
Racing           56.61    356.93    236.32
Role-Playing    350.29    326.50    187.58
Shooter          38.18    575.16    310.45
Simulation       63.54    181.78    113.20
Sports          134.76    670.09    371.34
Strategy         49.10     67.89     44.94
```

Using this code:

```
Genre_sales.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize = (10,10))
plt.suptitle('Total Sales by Genre, separated by Region')
plt.xlabel('Genre')
plt.ylabel('Total Units Sold (Millions)')
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902958/pandas-dataframe-bar-plot-with-sort-values-by-other-column) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame bar plot with sort\_values by other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902958/pandas-dataframe-bar-plot-with-sort-values-by-other-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index into the dataframe with the sorted order, that should do it:

```
Genre_sales.loc[df.sum(axis=1).sort_values().index].plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,10))
```